# error: column "username" of relation "users" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgreSQL and I'm getting this error when attempting insert rows into this table

```
 create table if not exists users (
    id serial primary key
,    username varchar(20)
,    password varchar(100)
,    profile_pic text
);

create table if not exists memes (
    id serial primary key
,   title varchar(45)   
,   img text
,   content text
,   author_id integer references users (id)
);


insert into users (username, password, profile_pic) values 
('someName', 'somePass', 'someUrl');
```

Edit: Thank you to every one who responded. I finally figured it out. My postman software needed to be updated. -endless facepalms-

Comment: Does your `users` table maybe already exist with a different definition? Remove the `if exists` and run your script again

Comment: Are you using version 9.1 or higher?

Comment: Is there a clear error-message? I only see SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Only works once, unless you change the table name 'users'. Maybe the table name cannot be users?

Comment: @dustytrash: if the table exists (without the column `username` )  then `create table if exists` will simply not create a new table and the old definition will remain

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one `users` table, likely located in a different schema and you're creating in a different schema than you're selecting from. See where your users tables are.

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE Tablename = 'users';
```

If you only have one check what columns it has with `\d schema.users`

Comment: These tables were created on a new database though. ( that's why I'm so confused over it. )